# How to display junit test reports in concourse in a usable/interactive way?

Tags: concourse

the company where I work is evaluating different CI/CD systems, we tried GoCD (v17.4), Jenkins 2 (v2.7) and Concourse (v3.2.1).

We liked Concourse, but a big **downside** was the fact that the **test reports were not displayed in a usable way**. I asked in the slack chat, I was told Concourse shows the output of the console, respecting the ANSI colors, if any...

...but the thing is, **XML test reports contain a lot more information than just a red color for failing tests** and we need to use that information.

I created a **failing test** and **Jenkins** has a nice plugin to group all tests, show extra info/metrics and group the failing tests to spot them at once. It also keeps the **history of test results**.

In Concourse, without a tests reporter one has to scroll down a log to see all failing tests... my colleagues are concerned about this.

**Is there a way in Concourse to parse a junit XML test report and show it in the UI in a usable/interactive (clickable) way, as jenkins does?**

As I learnt is that Concourse has no plugins and simplicity by design, it seems that the answer is: **"NO, there isn't: you can just see the console logs as is".** but if I'm wrong, please let me know... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Concourse doesn't discriminate against types of outputs on purpose.

Concourse is made to be generic. That way there isn't highly specialize, unrepeatable deployments of itself.

Jenkins is specialized to solve these types of issues. To the extent it has deep integration for having UIs display custom output.

It sounds like Jenkins solves all your use cases. I wouldn't try to hammer concourse into this use case.

Answer (score 0):

Concourse is minimal in that way. Concourse is made to run tasks in a pipeline configuration, and do so in an atomic container setup. That is also way it does not store build artifacts and so on. It forces you to do the right thing and save  everything you need elsewhere, like buckets etc. Push the XML to a service or store it in a bucket for a tool to use later on.